# bitnami/airflow LDAP error - rolesMapping is not working

Tags: ldap, airflow, airflow-2.x

**Name and Version**
bitnami/airflow-16.0.6

**What architecture are you using?**
amd64

**What steps will reproduce the bug?**
When I start airflow with the following configuration, I log in to the UI interface of airflow. I will get the following error:
Your user has no roles and/or permissions!

When I set the value of userRegistrationRole to User, the user's role after logging in is User; when I set the value of userRegistrationRole to Admin, the user's role after logging in is Admin.

And my user tom belongs to the SzManagement group. No matter I configure it as "cn=SzManagement,ou=Groups,dc=insilico,dc=ai": ["User"] or "cn=SzManagement,ou=Groups,dc=insilico,dc=ai": ["Admin"], it all looks like it's not working. The permissions of a user's login depend on the value of userRegistrationRole.

**Are you using any custom parameters or values?**
Posted here is part of my values.yaml value

```
ldap:
  enabled: true
  uri: "ldap://dc.domain.com:389"
  basedn: "DC=domain,DC=ai"
  searchAttribute: "cn"
  binddn: "CN=sz-ldapservice,OU=China,OU=Users,OU=Medicine,DC=domain,DC=ai"
  bindpw: "password"
  userRegistration: 'True'
  userRegistrationRole: "Public"
  rolesMapping: '{ "cn=SzManagement,ou=Groups,dc=Medicine,dc=ai": ["Admin"], "cn=Admins,ou=Groups,dc=Medicine,dc=ai": ["User"], }'
  rolesSyncAtLogin: 'True'
```

My AD domain user tom belongs to group SzManagement. When I started airflow with the above configuration, I saw the following page:
[image]

**What is the expected behavior?**
I hope to assign the user tom an admin or USer permission through rolesMapping.

Comment: could you attach logs?